# How to use the props in vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I try to use a prop in a computed value and i keep getting the error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
> found in
> --->  at src/cmps/space-details/space-imgs.vue
>  at src/pages/space-details.vue
>  at src/App.vue

Maybe i'm using the prop wrong?
the component:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="imgUrls.length" class="space-imgs" :class="pics">
    <img :src="img" v-for="(img, idx) in imgUrls.slice(0, 5)" :key="idx" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: { imgUrls: Array },

  computed: {
    pics() {
      return `pics-${this.imgUrls.length}`;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

and this is how i pass the prop:

```
    <space-imgs :imgUrls="space.imgUrls" />
```

Thanks

Comment: how are you passing the props to the component?

Comment: ````
<space-imgs :imgUrls="space.imgUrls" />
````

Comment: Instead if Array in props,  use ` props: { imgUrls: []},`

Comment: You can add a check if imgUrls is not null then return `pics-${this.imgUrls.length}`;

Comment: If imgUrls is supposed to be an array, don't allow it to be rendered with `space.imgUrls === undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the prop like below. This will work.

```
<space-imgs :img-urls="space.imgUrls" />
```

For avoiding wrong prop data in component. initialize prop with default value.

```
props: { 
 imgUrls: {
     type: Array,
     default: [],
     required: true
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template will be first rendered before the prop is passed, making `imgUrls` undefined. So just do this: `v-if="imgUrls"`.